# Parse c# DateTime to Kendo DateTimePicker format

Tags: c#, datetime, kendo-ui, type-conversion, kendo-datetimepicker

I was working on edit of a form. I had stored value returned from `Kendo DateTimePicker` into `SQL Server` with `smalldatetime` data type through `DateTime` of `c#`. Now while editing I want to display the stored data into the same `DateTimePicker`. I realized that `c#` returns date in the format of `2017-07-05T14:53:00` but `Kendo DateTimePicker` returns value in the format `7/20/2017 2:00AM`. I am trying to set the `value` of Kendo DateTimePicker to the default value of the model. I have tried the following code but it is not working

```
kendo.parseDate("@Model.date", "dd-MM-yyyyTHH:mm:ss")
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Kendo-UI does not talk to the SQL server. You forgot to mention the entire stack of technology in-between.

Comment: @Tomalak Oops.I am using asp.net so I need to convert from c# datetime to kendo DateTimePicker.Will make the necessary changes

Comment: look at the documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#configuration-format - but instead of trying to make the datepicker accept the string format in the JSON, you should concentrate on on the more general question of how to convert all JSON date strings to actual JS dates as part of the parsing process.

Comment: Ok I will do further research on this.

Comment: i did go through this http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateparsing

Comment: No, I meant this: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/jan/06/javascript-json-date-parsing-and-real-dates - This way, when jQuery is done with parsing the response JSON and gives the data to Kendo, all date strings are real JS dates. And Kendo will be able to use them immediately.

Comment: I am not having problem with Kendo Date. The problem seems to persist only with Kendo DateTime. My service seems to be sending the model in the required format though it is covered with {} brackets

Comment: I dont really get the point, you have 2017-07-05T14:53:00 as a string then you want to set kendoDateTimePicker? it just need to use new Date(@Model.date) like [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/IfEqIw)?